# R - sample and resample a person-period file

Tags: r, dplyr, sample

I am working with a gigantic person-period file and I thought that 
a good way to deal with a large dataset is by using sampling and re-sampling technique.

My person-period file look like this

```
   id code time
1   1    a    1
2   1    a    2
3   1    a    3
4   2    b    1
5   2    c    2
6   2    b    3
7   3    c    1
8   3    c    2
9   3    c    3
10  4    c    1
11  4    a    2
12  4    c    3
13  5    a    1
14  5    c    2
15  5    a    3
```

I have actually **two distinct** issues.

The first issue is that I am having trouble in simply `sampling` a person-period file.

For example, I would like to sample 2 id-sequences such as :

```
  id code time
   1    a    1
   1    a    2
   1    a    3
   2    b    1
   2    c    2
   2    b    3
```

The following line of code is working for sampling a person-period file

```
dt[which(dt$id %in% sample(dt$id, 2)), ]
```

However, I would like to use a `dplyr` solution because I am interested in resampling and in particular I would like to use `replicate`.

I am interested in doing something like `replicate(100, sample_n(dt, 2), simplify = FALSE)`

I am struggling with the `dplyr` solution because I am not sure what should be the `grouping` variable.

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% group_by(id) %>% sample_n(1)
```

gives me an incorrect result because it does not keep the full sequence of each `id`.

Any clue how I could both sample and re-sample person-period file ?

*data*

```
dt = structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
), class = "factor"), code = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c"), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", 
"3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "code", "time"), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I also updated with a replicate version in dplyr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the idiomatic way would probably look like

```
set.seed(1)
samp = df %>% select(id) %>% distinct %>% sample_n(2)
left_join(samp, df)

  id code time
1  2    b    1
2  2    c    2
3  2    b    3
4  5    a    1
5  5    c    2
6  5    a    3
```

This extends straightforwardly to more grouping variables and fancier sampling rules.

---

If you need to do this many times...

```
nrep = 100
ng   = 2
samps = df %>% select(id) %>% distinct %>% 
  slice(rep(1:n(), nrep)) %>% mutate(r = rep(1:nrep, each = n()/nrep)) %>%
  group_by(r) %>% sample_n(ng)
repdat = left_join(samps, df)

# then do stuff with it:
repdat %>% group_by(r) %>% do_stuff
```

Comment: Thanks good point. However, I am trying to `replicate` sampling, which works with something like `replicate(100, sample_n(dt, 2), simplify = FALSE)` but not with longer pip sequences.

Comment: @giacomoV Ok, updated. I think you should put that into the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `filter` with `sample`

```
dt %>%
    filter(id %in% sample(unique(id),2, replace = FALSE))
```

NOTE: The OP specified using `dplyr` method and this solution does uses the `dplyr`.

---

If we need to do `replicate` one option would be using `map` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
dt %>% 
    distinct(id) %>% 
    replicate(2, .) %>%
    map(~sample(., 2, replace=FALSE)) %>%
    map(~filter(dt, id %in% .))
#$id
#  id code time
#1  1    a    1
#2  1    a    2
#3  1    a    3
#4  4    c    1
#5  4    a    2
#6  4    c    3

#$id
#  id code time
#1  4    c    1
#2  4    a    2
#3  4    c    3
#4  5    a    1
#5  5    c    2
#6  5    a    3
```

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you are doing some simulations and may want to do the subsetting many times. You probably also want to try this `data.table` method and utilize the fast [binary search feature](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html) on the key column:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
setkey(dt, id)
replicate(2, dt[list(sample(unique(id), 2))], simplify = F)

#[[1]]
#   id code time
#1:  3    c    1
#2:  3    c    2
#3:  3    c    3
#4:  5    a    1
#5:  5    c    2
#6:  5    a    3

#[[2]]
#   id code time
#1:  3    c    1
#2:  3    c    2
#3:  3    c    3
#4:  4    c    1
#5:  4    a    2
#6:  4    c    3
```